# php program works locally but not on server

Tags: php, local

I have this code running locally smoothly. The program only looks for a file and write data on it. When I try to run the same program on a server, it just does nothing...

This is the complete code:

```
<?php

 $myFile = "Current_User.txt";
 //$produto = "sapato1";
 //$produto = $produto.";";
 $i = 0;
 $produto = $_POST["produtoID"];
 $produto = $produto.";";
 //$produto = $_POST["produtoID"];

    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $line_of_text = fgets($fh);
    $str = $line_of_text;
    $str = str_replace("\n", "", $str);
    $str = $str."_Cesto.txt";
    fclose($fh);

        $fh2 = fopen($str, "r")or die("can't open file");
                while (($line_of_text = fgets($fh2))) {
                        $i++;
                        $line_of_text = str_replace("\n", "", $line_of_text);
                        $line_of_text = str_replace("\r", "", $line_of_text);
                        if($produto == $line_of_text){
                            break;
                            }
                }
            fclose($fh2);


            $dados = file($str);
            if($i == 1){
                unset($dados[$i - 1]);
            }
            else{
                unset($dados[$i - 2]);
            }
            file_put_contents($str,$dados);         


  ?>
```

Comment: Does the file exist on the server?

Comment: What means "does nothing"? What code file_put_contents() returns? Maybe you just have no permissions on the server where you want to store the file?

Comment: You should check return value on $dados = file($str) What are possible values of the $str it will be a local path or it can be also an url? If it can be an url you have to set allow_url_fopen in PHP config.

Comment: When I said that does nothing, it means that is does not change the contents of the file. All files are on the server. It should not be permission problems (reading or writing), because in the same project i have programs that read and write files without problems.

Comment: $str is the full name of the file that will be modified

Comment: Is whole script executed? Do you have any error logging/reporting set on the server? I'm afraid that you will have to debug this script and find the answer yourself

Answer (score 2):

Following code is facing the same problem so  permissions could be the reason or elsewise change the method to GET it will be working.

```
 <?php 

    $url =  "http://sea-summit.com/T_webservice/get_appointments_by_id.php";


    $data = array('user_id'=> 1);


    $options = array(
      'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode( $data ),
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" . "Accept: application/json\r\n" ));

    $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
    $result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
    $response = json_decode( $result );



    var_dump($response);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to upload Current_User.txt

Comment: @Lix
Ancient Mayan prophecy ;)

Comment: @Lix: Legit answer...
If it's working on a local server with no errors, then just stops working, he must have forgotten that file. Unless he wants to provide more info on what "does nothing" means.

Comment: When I said that does nothing, it means that is does not change the contents of the file. All files are on the server. It should not be permission problems (reading or writing), because in the same project i have programs that read and write files without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the write permission of your Current_User.txt file?
What File System are you using on your Server?

> If you have access: Check your PHP error_log on the Server to get more valueable answers, or change the error_reportings.